# How do I search the object inside the array inside the array?

Tags: javascript

There are 2 arrays in the array. There are objects in them. How can I find the one whose name is "Sneijder"?

```
const players = [
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Hagi",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Carlos",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Zidane",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Sneijder",
    },
  ],
];
```

Comment: `players.flat().find(x => {return x.name=="Sneijder"})`

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten the array with `flat` then `find` your item in the resulting flattened array:

```js
const players = [
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Hagi",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Carlos",
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Zidane",
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Sneijder",
        },
    ],
];

const player = players.flat().find((p) => p.name === "Sneijder")
console.log(player)
```

Comment: you reinvented `flat()` and `find()`

Comment: @epascarello hehe! You're right! Adjusted

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the 3 combinations or any different than these. All will give the same result but the complexity can be different for other examples having required object in the beginning or middle.

```js
const players = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Hagi",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Carlos",
    },
  ],
  [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Zidane",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Sneijder",
    },
  ],
];

let player = "";
players.forEach(x => player = x.find(y => y.name === "Sneijder"));
console.log("Method 1", player);
player = players.flat().find(y => y.name === "Sneijder");
console.log("Method 2", player);
players.some(x => {
  const [x1, x2] = x;
  if (x1.name === "Sneijder") return player = x1;
  if (x2.name === "Sneijder") return player = x2;
});
console.log("Method 3", player);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.prototype.concat to merge arrays and then find by name

```
const sneijderObj = [].concat.apply([], players).find(x => x.name === 'Sneijder');
console.log(sneijderObj);
```